# Personal hotspot turns off as soon as screen goes off

Tags: wifi-hotspot, nokia

I have Nokia G21 and I'd like to share wi-fi with my PC. The problem is that as soon as my phone's screen goes off the hot spot turns off as well. How to fix this problem?

Comment: Use USB Tethering.

Comment: @Firelord why should I use USB Tethering if I can use personal hotspot? I doubt that my problem don't have any other solution.

Comment: Most likely a barres saving feature that collides with the hotspot feature. On earlier Android versions there was on option to configure how and if Wifi should be shut down when screen is off, but on newer Android versions I have not seen such an option. I would contact Nokia so that it is files as bug.